# ul styling works in html but not in my css

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to remove the bullets from a `<ul>` that I have on my index.php page. I put:

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}
```

in my css page. I also tried `list-style-type: none;` and that didn't work. But when I added the ul styling directly to my index page with `<ul style="list-style:none">` it worked. All the other css things are working properly and yes, I gazuple-checked my syntax on the css file. Why won't it work there, but on the other page it does?

Comment: How are you referring the css file in your php file? Can you please the code?

Comment: Maybe you override it in your CSS file at some point, did you try putting it at the end of the CSS file?

Comment: I'm calling the file like this: `code` <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/style.css" />. The only thing after the ul part of my css file deals with the input boxes.

Comment: Which browser are you developing in? Have you checked your settings that browser-styles don't override CSS?

Comment: Replicate the issue in jsfiddle.net and post a link! Then we can see your code and the problem.

Comment: It is working now, but the weird thing is I didn't change anything. I went back and forth several times between the index file and the css file to make sure it was working on only one and now it works on both. I was checking with Safari and Firefox, btw.

Comment: I guess there was some caching going on.

Comment: @JandenDanielHale Probably caching; try hitting the `F5` button or `ctrl+F5` for hard refresh. Also useful is ctrl+alt+delete (works for most major browsers) to completely remove all files in the browsers cache.

Comment: May be typo :). It should be Crtl+Shift+Del.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like at some point this command is probably being overwritten. The last styles to be applied to a page are those which are written as inline styles. I.e.:

```
<ul style="list-style:none"></ul>
```

There are two things you can try here.

-Set the !important flag on your css statement in your css file

```
ul { list-style:none !important }
```

-Try setting the list items themselves to have a list-style of none

```
ul, li {list-style:none !important }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: You might have missed the comments on the question.

Comment: Be careful when using `!important`. It should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: Ah yes - missed those! True !important is a last resort, but a quick way to diagnose a style that is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
list-style-type: none
```

Good luck with that.